# same jquery code works differently in file and console

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

why when I execute

```
$(".b").show(1000);
```

in console of chrome dev tools it animates but when I put it in js file it's just displays element?

thanx in advance

UPD

`<div class="b"></div>` is in html

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/some/url.php",

        }).done(function ( data ) {
            $(".b").show(1000);
        });
```

Comment: In the page, do you try to run it before the element is loaded?

Comment: thank you for your responce, @AlexK. element is loaded.

Comment: Then I think your going to need to provide some code

Comment: @artaskerov you missed the `$` for `$('.b')`

Comment: @Joseph, sorry for that. I made this mistake when I copied this from code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a checklist:

- is the code executed on DOM ready?
- does the element exist on the DOM during execution? if not, nothing is shown.
- is the div styled or not empty? empty divs with no padding, no background, no borders and/or `0` height don't appear.
- **does the AJAX return a success?**
- what does the console say? 404? Cross-domain restricted? Syntax error/Unexpected token at..?

Answer (score 0):

Could this help ?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/some/url.php",

        }).done(function ( data ) {
            $(".b")live().show(1000);
        });
```